# Android Send data back to server

Tags: android, data-transfer

How would one go about sending data back to server, from an android application?

I've already tried using HttpPost and posted back to a RESTful WCF service, but I couldnt get that to work (I've already created a SO question about this, without finding the solution..) - No matter what I do I keep getting 405 Method not allowed or the 400 Bad Request.. :(

I'm not asking for full code example necessarily.. just a pointer in a direction, which can enable me to send data back to a server.

It is important that the user should not have to allow or dismiss the transfer.. it should happen under the covers, so to speak

Thanks in advance

Comment: "But is there another way of sending data, which does not involve services" - Carrier Pigeon?

Comment: What I thought about was something like a FTP transfer or email.. whatever.. All I need to do is send data to a server.

Comment: No one got any advice on this?.. I'm desperate now..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Services is the way to go. REST (I recommend this one on Android), or SOAP based. There're loads of tutorials on getting an android app communicate a service, even with .net / wcf ones.

Tho you can always just open raw sockets and send data with some custom protocol.

Edit:

Here's the doInBackground part of my asynctask handling http post communication, maybe that'll help:

```
protected String doInBackground(String... req) {

        Log.d(TAG, "Message to send: "+req[0]);
        HttpPost p = new HttpPost(url);

        try{
            p.setEntity(new StringEntity(req[0], "UTF8"));
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        p.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

        String response = "";
        try{
            HttpResponse resp = hc.execute(p, localContext);
            InputStream is = resp.getEntity().getContent();
            response = convertStreamToString(is);
            Log.d("Response", "Response is " + response);
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return response;
     }
```

Comment: The problem is that I've created a WCF, which I'm already hosting, but I simply cannot send data to it.. I can send GET requests just fine, but ALL http POST requests are returned as (HTTP 400 Bad Request).. So I'm looking for alternatives as I have a deadline on friday and I've already spent 2-3 days on the service-solution

Comment: I'm no expert on WCF, but in my project I have to communicate with dozens of wcf services, with http post messages. On the Android side, it's not much different from sending GET requests. I don't know much about the WCF side of things, are you sure that it's correctly implemented?

Comment: To be honest, no I'm not sure.. But I've followed examples on the net and my WCF is identical to them. And my GetData method (GET request) works just fint.. its just the Data method (POST request) which fails.. But I'm looking in all directions for solutions now